# How to iterate over a cucumber feature

Tags: cucumber

I'm writing a feature in cucumber that could be applied to a number of objects that can be programmaticaly determined.  Specifically, I'm writing a smoke test for a cloud deployment (though the problem is with cucumber, not the cloud tools, thus stack overflow).

```
Given a node matching "role:foo"
When I connect to "automatic.eucalyptus.public_ipv4" on port "default.foo.port"
Then I should see "Hello"
```

The given does a search for nodes with the role foo does and the automatic.eucalyptus... And port come from the node found.  This works just fine... for one node.

The search could retun multiple nodes in different environments.  Dev will probably return one, test and integration a couple, and prod can vary.  The given already finds all of them.

Looping over the nodes in each step doesn't really work.  If any one failed in the When, the whole thing would fail.  I've looked at scenarios and cucumber-iterate, but both seem to assume that all scenarios are predefined rather than programmatically looked up.

I'm a cuke noob, so I'm probably missing something.  Any thoughts?

**Edit**

I'm "resolving" the problem by flipping the scenario.  I'm trying to integrate into a larger cluster definition language to define repeatedly call the feature by passing the info as an environment variable.

Comment: I think for this scenario we need to know a bit more about what you expect to happen, and how you define if the scenario as a whole is passing for failing.  Also this looks pretty test focused, what is the business value you are testing here?   In terms of the test itself, is the list of potential environments known?  will there only ever be at most one node per environment?  Would it make sense to have the cukes run against a single environment instead of trying to test all of them at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize in advance that I can't tell you exactly "how" to do it, but a friend of mine solved a similar problem using a somewhat unorthodox technique. He runs scenarios that write out scenarios to be run later.  The gem he wrote to do this is called [cukewriter](https://github.com/joelhelbling/cuke_writer).  He describes how to use it in pretty good detail on the github page for the gem.  I hope this will work for you, too.